# Why can not I use expect script to start redis?

Tags: bash, redis, expect

I guess there must be a simple reason why I can't start redis like this

---- update -----

After @larsks answered my question I realize it is this one that cause my confusion "You end it with an interact statement, which conncets your console to the stdin/stdout of the process you spawned. The redis-server program is not interactive: it doesn't accept any console input."

I check the code again and found it was this code that made me think the process was stuck

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn redis-server
expect "The server is now ready to accept connections"
interact
spawn redis-cli
expect ">"
...
```

I never saw redis-cli run.

But if I change to

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn redis-server
expect "The server is now ready to accept connections"
spawn redis-cli
expect ">"
...
interact //put it in the end.
```

It works as I expected.

BTW the reason I use expect here is first to make sure redis server starts then delete some keys.

Comment: take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write *Expect* scripts with shell code only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you expect the first example to do?  You end it with an `interact` statement, which connets your console to the stdin/stdout of the process you spawned.  The `redis-server` program is not interactive: it doesn't accept any console input.  When you run `redis-server`, it will get as far as...

```
1135:M 18 Nov 13:59:51.634 * Ready to accept connections
```

...and then it stops, waiting for redis clients to connect and operate on it.  Also, note that the Redis version I'm using ends with `Ready to accept connections` rather than `The server is now ready to accept connections`, so I'll be using that in the following examples.

We can add a `puts` command to the expect script to see that it isn't
actually getting stuck anywhere.  If I run the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn redis-server
expect "Ready to accept connections"
puts "redis is running"
interact
```

I get as output:

```
spawn redis-server
1282:C 18 Nov 14:03:33.123 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
1282:C 18 Nov 14:03:33.123 # Redis version=4.0.10, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1282, just started
[...]
1282:M 18 Nov 14:03:33.124 * Ready to accept connections
redis is running
```

So we can see that it's not getting stuck at the `spawn` statement,
nor even at the `expect` statement.

What's not clear from your question is why you're even using `expect`
in this situation, since `redis-server` is not an interactive program
and does not produce any prompts that require automation.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I can't reproduce the problem. I don't know what I did wrong last time.

Comment: Hi, I found the reason why I though the script was stuck. I put the interact in the wrong place. See my updated question and sorry for the confusion. And the reason I used expect is I need to delete some keys.